# Decrypt text for salt and bcrypt-nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using bcrypt-nodejs module for password hash . But when want to forget password feature , how to get actual password ? My actuall password already encrypt
by salt and  bcrypt-nodejs.

Answer (score 4):

That's one of the major security features of bcrypt is that you can't get the original password after it has been hashed. You can only compare hashed values. So for a "Forgot password" feature, the user will have to set a new password.